# Load another xml files from storyboard and XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mobile, storyboard

I would like to try to use "import" for loading or fetching another xml file when main.storyboard coming on the screen.

i think storyboard is actually written by XML code lines, so I would be able to use include, import command if I put filepath on there. like

I tried it on Android system, and it worked well.
Is it possible to load another xml view under IOS platform?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is unclear on what you are trying to accomplish. Have you read the documentation on storyboards?

Comment: @HannesSverrisson Thanks for your commenting. Here's what I want to do. First of all, I want to donwload XML file from the server when the apps beginning. The downloaded XML will be saved somewhere in the device. And then, In the XML(main.storyboard) file (the original XML/Storyboard file) ,I want to make this load the "downloaded XML",(with using this command in XML <import src ="(file path for downloaded XML)" > and users will see the downloaded XML on their iphone. (xml download -> saving it in the device -> App will load storyboard file -> Storyboard will load a downloaded xml file)

Comment: @HannesSverrisson Also, I will try to read over the official documentation!